# intergal properities (square root)

Tags: real-analysis

I have this question below ,I don't know if this thing right or not but i've just wonders about it 
If we have 
$$ 
A=\int \sqrt(f_x)
$$
Can we do this move 
$$
A^2=\int f_x
$$
Thanks

Comment: Please look in particular your title and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

No

Counterexample:

$\int xdx = \frac{1}{2}x^2$
$\int x^2dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3$

$(\frac{1}{2}x^2)^2=\frac{1}{4}x^4\neq\frac{1}{3}x^3$

Answer (score 0):

No. As an analogy, we can consider A as a simple summation.
$$A = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$$
$$A^2 = (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)^2\neq x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... + x_n^2$$